# Removing Attribute

Tags: javascript

With my little knowledge of JavaScript, I'm trying to remove the href links on the name and title text when hovering over an image: http://www.equiuspartners.com/site/our-team/

What I thought would work:

```
document.querySelectorAll("h3.the-title a, div.portfolio-categories a").removeAttribute("href");
```

Only seems to actually work when given an array value:

```
document.querySelectorAll("h3.the-title a, div.portfolio-categories a")[0].removeAttribute("href");
```

Which, by logic, only does the first instance.

Why is it not allowing me to disable all links with the first method?

Comment: because collections do not have those methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`querySelectorAll` returns a [nodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), an array-like object containing **all** the elements that could be a match for the given selector, not a single element.

You'd have to iterate to remove the attribute on all those elements

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll("h3.the-title a, div.portfolio-categories a");

for (var i=0; i<elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].removeAttribute("href");
}
```

Comment: Any chance you could explain this code in english to me for a better understanding?

Comment: In English, `querySelectorAll` returns something that looks like an array, even if it's really not, that's why you can access it with `[0]` etc. As it's not just one element, but possibly multiple elements, you have to use a loop and access each element inside the loop, because `removeAttribute` only works on one element at a time.

Answer (score 4):

That's how it is, `document.querySelectorAll()` returns a collection, not a single element. In modern browsers, you can use this to remove all attributes from all matched elements:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(<selector>))
.forEach(e => e.removeAttribute('href'));
```

Please note that you can use [`arrow functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) in latest chrome and firefox only, (though there's a polyfill for Array.from available at above link.)

Comment: @epascarello - Michael seems to live in the future, all his answers use ES2015 that the rest of us will be able to use in production in a year or two.

Comment: @adeneo Sorry, I'm using mainly node.js, where the future is now... ;-) But you're right, your answer is better for a browser environment.

Comment: All your answers pretty much use ES2015, even straight forward clientside stuff, I pay attention. I don't really care, these days it seems to be fine, and arrow functions are neat and all, but usually the rest of us would add a notice that currently the answer **only** works in the latest Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: You guys are amazing. I'm learning so much, and I appreciate y'all taking up my lazy, ignorant questions. Connecting the dots.

Comment: @adeneo I get your point. Thanks for pointing me towards it - I'll start to point it out very clearly if I use ES2015 or will use more cross-browser compatible code from now on! BTW arrow functions are really neat :)

Comment: It's up to you how you want to answer, I'm not trying to butt in or anything. Just saying it would probably be helpful to mention that the new stuff isn't cross browser, yet, but hopefully soon!

Comment: Yes, that's how I took your comment. @adeneo